# PostgreSQL Randomly Can No Longer Listen to any port

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I restarted my server which hosts postgresql, now that I've restarted it I cannot get postgresql to listen on to any port. None of my settings have changed, just a simple restart. Also, since I am on mac, and I run a command like `sudo lsof -i :5432` I receive nothing in return. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: is postgresql server running? what do you see if you enter `ps -ef | grep postgres` in your terminal. What's the content of your `pg_hba.conf` file?

Comment: I've had to resort to reinstalling postgresql, but now I have lost all of my data. I still have the data folder from my previous copy, how can I integrate?

Comment: if its the same version you could try to just replace the new data folder with the old, change the folder / file permissions and it may work.

Comment: I tried, and when I open tables they say "specific folder cannot be found" and just lists a number